# how to migrate to junit5 for @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Tags: java, testing, junit5

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({JvmUtils.class})
public class TestJvmUtils {
// test code
}

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration

Comment: It looks like PowerMock does not support JUnit 5 yet, see [this open issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/830).

Comment: Hi david6969xin where you able to find a fix for it? Even I am facing a similar issue.